# How to make a placeholder in a listBox

Tags: yii2

It is necessary that in the field listBoxt, there was a placeholder, something like "Select a role for the user", i.e. message that the user sees without selecting anything in the listbox. But this should include the option `'prompt' => 'remove the role'` so that the user can remove the role through the drop-down list.

Is it possible to do this through the standard Yii functional without resorting to JS?

```
echo $form->field($model, 'additionalRoles', [
  'options' => [
    'class' => 'form-group',
  ],
])->listBox($additionalRoles, [
  'class'  => 'form-control j-multi-select2',
  'prompt' => 'Select additional role',
]);
```

For example: https://jsfiddle.net/8e7avn2d/1/

Comment: the js fiddle is for the select-box rather than the listbox are you trying to make a `select-dropdown`  with multiple-select option?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?=
$form->field($model, 'additionalRoles', [
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'form-group',
    ],
])
->listBox($additionalRoles, [
    'class' => 'form-control j-multi-select2',
    'prompt' => [
        'text' => "Select additional role",
        'options' => [
            'disabled' => true,
            'selected' => true,
            'hidden' => true,
        ]]
]);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

to achieve your example you should use [dropDownList](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activefield#dropDownList()-detail) instead of [listBox](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activefield#listBox()-detail)

```
echo $form->field($model, 'additionalRoles', [
  'options' => [
    'class' => 'form-group',
  ],
])->dropDownList($additionalRoles, [
  'class'  => 'form-control j-multi-select2',
  'prompt' => 'Select additional role',
]);
```